# Arrange the section in book class

Tags: spacing, sectioning, books

I have problem with my sectioning. I explain the problem in this code. Please run this code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bf\normalsize}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bf\normalsize}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bf\normalsize}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Preambule}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}

Section 1.10 is not good. I want to make section Like this\\ \\
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbf{1.1}&\textbf{kk}\\
\textbf{1.3}&\textbf{kk}\\
\textbf{1.8}&\textbf{kk}\\
\textbf{1.10}&\textbf{kk}\\
\end{tabular}\\
but the space is not follow the 1.10, but follow the space section 1.1-1.9.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain clearly what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: @tachyon if you run the code, you will find it. I want to make the section titles look parallel from section 1.1 to 1.10. But you can see, the title of section 1.10 (section with 2 digits after the dot) looks out of alignment with section 1.1-1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [titlesec](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) advance interface and format the the section using the non-starred variant of `\titleformat`. Use the following command to have the labels aligned to the left:

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bf\normalsize}{\makebox[2em][l]{\thesection}}{1ex}{}{}
```

The second, optional argument to the `\makebox`-command is important. Standard is `c`, which does not look nice.

The title page you ask for, can be coded in at least two differently way. If you prefer to use `\section*{section one}`, the following code works:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\pagestyle{fancy} \section*{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{\hfill section one\hfill}}} 
\end{titlepage}
```

A better solution is probably to avoid the starred section command and format the title page directly:

```
\begin{titlepage}
 \pagestyle{fancy} 
\centering\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont\textbf{section one} 
\end{titlepage}
```

Here is the code for your original question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bf\normalsize}{\makebox[2em][l]{\thesection}}{1ex}{}{}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bf\normalsize}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bf\normalsize}
\titlelabel{hlabel-formati}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Preambule}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}
\section{kk}

Section 1.10 is not good. I want to make section Like this\\ \\
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbf{1.1}&\textbf{kk}\\
\textbf{1.3}&\textbf{kk}\\
\textbf{1.8}&\textbf{kk}\\
\textbf{1.10}&\textbf{kk}\\
\end{tabular}\\
but the space is not follow the 1.10, but follow the space section 1.1-1.9.
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. it's work, but in another case, this code make make '\begin{titlepage}
 \pagestyle{fancy} 
\section*{\centering\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{section one}}}
\end{titlepage}' is not center. how to fix it?

Comment: thank you. It's work